# Can we get the closed-form solution of $x_{n+1} = \frac{1+5 x_n}{1+x_n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, closed-form

When reading a textbook I encounter a sequence, the closed-form solution of which, claims the author, can be derived. The sequence reads:

\begin{gather*}
x_{n+1} = \frac{1+5 x_n}{1+x_n}
\end{gather*}
and $x_1=1$. The author gives without proof that
$$
x_n = \frac{4+2\sqrt{5}-(\sqrt{5}-1)c^{2-t}}{2+(\sqrt{5}+3)c^{2-t}}
$$
where $c = \frac{1}{2}(7+3\sqrt{5})$.

It seems that we can formulates the problem in a more general framework, say a sequence
$$
y_{n+1} = a+\frac{b}{y_n+c}
$$
I can't see how this kind of sequence can be solved explicitly. Can anyone give a hint on the problem?

Comment: Looks like convergents for a continued fraction of a quadratic root of some kind.  Could be simplified somewhat by adding $c$, $t_n=y_n+c\implies t_{n+1}=A+b/t_n$

Comment: Did the author mean the entire sequence or the limiting value (which is easy to find)?

Comment: @Paul It refers to the entire sequence. I just edited my question by quoting the solution given in the book.

Comment: See p. 120 of the Google book "Exploring, Investigating and Discovering in Mathematics" (Vasile Berinde)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. A standard route is as follows. One may 'linearize' the given recurrence in a 'matrix frame' by writing
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=\underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 5 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)}_{\large A}\cdot x_{n}
\end{align}
$$ giving directly
$$
x_n=A^n \cdot x_1
$$ then, by diagonalizing  the matrix $A$,
$$
\begin{align}
A=P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1} =\left(\begin{matrix} -\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} 1-\sqrt{5} & 0 \\ 0 & 1+\sqrt{5} \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} & \frac12 \\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} & \frac12 \end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}
$$ one easily gets
$$
x_n=P \cdot J^n \cdot P^{-1} \cdot x_1
$$ that is
$$
x_n=\left(\begin{matrix} -\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5} \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} (1-\sqrt{5})^n & 0 \\ 0 & (1+\sqrt{5})^n \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} & \frac12 \\ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} & \frac12 \end{matrix}\right) \cdot x_1
$$ obtaining a closed form of $x_n$.

Comment: Nice and elegant proof. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: With $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 5 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$ I get for the second iteration $A^2=\left(\begin{matrix} 6 & 10 \\ 2 & 6 \end{matrix}\right)$ But $\dfrac{1+5 \dfrac{1+5 x_{n-1}}{1+x_{n-1}}}{1+\dfrac{1+5 x_{n-1}}{1+x_{n-1}}}=\dfrac{1+x_{n-1}+5+25 x_{n-1}}{1+x_{n-1}+1+5x_{n-1}}=\dfrac{6+26x_{n-1}}{2+6x_{n-1}}$ With $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 5 \end{matrix}\right)$ it seems to work

Answer (score 3):

It is a [Riccati difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_difference_equation). First write it as in Jonas Meyer comment:
$$
t_{n+1}=A+\frac{B}{t_n}.
$$
Then do de change of variable $t_n=z_{n+1}/z_n$ and obtain a linear second order difference equation for $z_n$.